# does sword in Matthew 10.34 mean a branch?

Tags: exegesis

does sword in Matthew 10.34 mean a branch as in a branch of Judaism?

if one translates the Greek word sword (macherion) back into Hebrew it can mean a literal sword or figuratively it can mean a branch as in Isaiah 27.11

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the Chapter, it seems more likely that here Jesus is actually talking about a sword as in "I bring unrest/war". Observe how he says

> Do not think that I have come to bring peace to the earth; I have **not come to bring peace**, but a sword. For I have come to set a **man against his father**, and a **daughter against her mother**, and a **daughter-in-law against her mother-in-law**; and one’s foes will be members of one’s own household. Whoever loves father or mother more than me is not worthy of me; and whoever loves son or daughter more than me is not worthy of me; and whoever does not take up the cross and follow me is not worthy of me. Those who find their life will lose it, and those who lose their life for my sake will find it.
>
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

He actually talks about giving your life and turning on your family to follow him, so it is reasonably to say this is not a branch, but a sword in the metaphorical sense of *non-peace* or conflict.